# Jquery does not preserve my events replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery

I first copy my element into another box:

```
$('#PageContainer').after($('<div/>', {style: 'display: none', id: 'ersatz_div'}));
$('#ersatz_div').html($('#PageContainer').clone());
```

Next i put the element, that i want to print, into my visible box:

```
$('#PageContainer').html(element);
window.print();
```

And at the end i transfer the html back into the visible container:

```
$('#PageContainer').replaceWith($('#ersatz_div #PageContainer').clone());
$('#ersatz_div').remove();
```

Although i used `clone()` the events do not exisit anymore. I read some similar question that state i should use `.on("click"` instead of `click()` but this would mean that i had to change a lot of code! Is there another posibility? Thanks

Comment: Try with `.clone(true)`

Comment: Thanks @Satpal you are right! Could you please write it as a answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [**`.clone(true)`**](http://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents), where `true` indicates that event handlers should be copied along with the elements.

So Use

```
$('#PageContainer').replaceWith($('#ersatz_div #PageContainer').clone(true));
```